# Parsing CFLs (simulating PDA vs CYK algorithm)

Tags: pushdown-automata, efficiency, parsers

We can simulate the PDA and parse the language with the following operations (vaguely):

> 1. Read the input symbol and top of stack - $O(1)$
> 2. Check all the transition rules (must check all for non-determinism) - $O(|Transition rules|)$
> 3. Update the stack and the set of states - $O(1)$

Due to non-determinism, the problem size increases and so does the complexity.

However, for **deterministic context free languages**, the complexity of this algorithm seems to be $O(n|Transition rules|)$ which is linear.

The complexity of CYK algorithm is $O(n^3|G|)$. From various sources it seems that the complexity of CYK algorithm is polynomial for deterministic languages.
http://people.csail.mit.edu/madry/docs/linear.pdf

$|Transition rules|$ has a maximum value of around $|G|$ I think.

So, is this method really better than the CYK algorithm for deterministic CFLs or am I making a mistake in my analysis? If so, then where?

I'm assuming that $|G|$ = Number of production rules in grammar.

Comment: 1. Is what method better than CYK parsing?  2. I think you might be making a faulty assumption: just because the language $L$ is a deterministic context-free language and $G$ is a grammar for $L$ doesn't mean that $G$ is unambiguous and corresponds to a deterministic PDA; it just means that there exists some other grammar $G'$ with those properties.   3. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLR_parser#Advantages and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_context-free_language, if you want an algorithm that's efficient for deterministic CFLs.

Comment: I don't think your description works for NPDA. You *can not* properly implement non-deterministic automata. Well, short of exploring the whole reachable state space, which is rarely efficient. Hence, other parsing algorithms shine.

Comment: @D.W. Actually I didn't mean that given a grammar, we construct the DPDA. In the method I suggested, I assume that the person creates the DPDA on his own.

Comment: @Raphael Yes, yes. I mentioned it clearly that for non-determinism, the problem size will increase (rapidly) and the method won't work for it with a good time complexity. However, I'm wondering about deterministic CFL only. Is this method not a lot faster than CYK? This seems very obvious and linear. Hence, I'm skeptical and think that I may have made a mistake in the analysis and hope someone would point out that flaw for me.

Comment: @D.W. ` Deterministic context-free languages can be accepted in O(n) time by a LR(k) parser`. That's from the page you linked. Thank you for the link. In fact the method I proposed in the question is comparable to a LR(1) parser I guess.

Comment: Then you should state right at the start that you only inspect DPDAs. Anyway, my point is that your language is imprecise. How do you implement step 2? It can be done in constant time! Which "set of states" in step 3? (This is what made me think your algorithm was supposed to work for NPDAs.)

Comment: @Raphael In step two, the input symbol can be checked with each transition rule. This would be $O(|transition rule|)$ and the procedure would work for NPDA too however, that is not my intention because size the would very fast. Now that you say step 2 can be done in constant time, I think by using a hash function, we can take the particular transition straight away in constant time. The only disadvantage is that now the procedure wouldn't work at all for non-determinism.

Comment: No need for hash tables; just encode alphabet as numbers $0..k$ and states as numbers $0..q$ and use a plain old matrix. That works with or without non-determinism.

Comment: @Raphael  In step 3, I'm referring to set of states because the procedure indeed works for non-determinism. However we are only interested in the DPDA and not NPDA. Basically my hope is that the procedure works for both DPDA and NPDA but practically suited only for DPDA because the size increases very fast in case of NPDA. That is why I analyzed the final complexity for DPDA only.

Comment: @Raphael Regarding the matrix. Yes that would work. Thank you. However, isn't it the same as a hash? When I said hash, I had actually meant keeping separate single dimensional arrays for alphabet as index for every state. Using matrix does the same thing in a concise way. I thought that is called a hash. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Well, I also had the single state PDA in mind, so was actually thinking of having a single array for it all.

Comment: By "hash" we typically refer so a non-injective mapping (cf hashtables), but in a sense the encoding I propose is a perfect hashing.

Comment: @aste123 What you're missing is that CFG parsing is sub-$O(n^3)$ even for nondeterministic grammars, and that you can have a single method that is linear on deterministic grammars and still  sub-$O(n^3)$ on all other CFGs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_context-free_language) mentions that the class of deterministic context-free languages can be parsed in linear time, using an [LR parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser). In contrast, the fastest algorithm for parsing general context-free languages, Valiant's modification of the CYK algorithm, runs in time $O(n^\omega)$ (where $\omega$ is the matrix multiplication constant), and there is [evidence](http://theory.stanford.edu/~virgi/cs367/papers/leecfg.pdf) due to Lee that any practical implementation of Valiant's algorithm will run in time proportional to $n^{2.43}$ at best (substitute $\epsilon = 3-2.81$ in Lee's paper; here $2.81$ is the exponent of [Strassen's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm)), and in time proportional to $n^3$ for most values of $n$ occurring in practice.

Context-free grammars used in practice tend to be deterministic, precisely because DCFLs can be parsed faster than CFLs. Indeed, even more restricted variants are commonly used ([LALR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LALR_parser) languages) for reasons of efficiency.

Comment: This answer doesn't state the complexity of Valiant's algorithm when applied to deterministic grammars. It isn't $O(n)$, but a variant can be designed that is.

Comment: @reinierpost Valiant's algorithm uses matrix multiplication, so I doubt that it can exploit determinacy. Perhaps a different algorithm does.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus What is $|G|$? Is it number of production rules in grammar?

Comment: I don’t see this notation in my answer.